# Array of strings to a string: Issue using Implode

Tags: android, arrays, string, implode

following directions found [here](http://imwill.com/implode-string-array-java/#.UV6qSatOruN), I'm trying to convert an array of strings into a string, but I'm getting some *nulls* that I can't remove.

The code I've been using:

First, I fill in the textviews and make the array with the results.

```
public void doCalculations(){
    //write number of teeth for every cog from a cassette
    for(int i=0; i<cassCogs[0]; i++){
        tvCogsArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        tvCogsArray[i].setText(String.valueOf(cassCogs[i+1]) +" " + getString(R.string.teeth));
        }

    if (Integer.parseInt(chainringCount) == 1){
        for (int counter = 0; counter<cassCogs[0]; counter++ ){
            float temp = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize) *     (Float.parseFloat(chainringOne) /cassCogs[counter + 1] ))/1000;
            tvOne[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", temp));

            toEmail_1[counter] = String.format("%.2f", temp);
        }
    }else if (Integer.parseInt(chainringCount) == 2){
        for (int counter = 0; counter<cassCogs[0]; counter++ ){
            float temp = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize) * (Float.parseFloat(chainringOne)/cassCogs[counter + 1] ))/1000;
            tvOne[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", temp));

            toEmail_1[counter] = String.format("%.2f", temp);

            float second = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize) *(Float.parseFloat(chainringTwo)/cassCogs[counter+ 1] ))/1000;
            tvTwo[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", second));

            toEmail_2[counter] = String.format("%.2f", second);

        }
    }else if (Integer.parseInt(chainringCount)==3){
        for (int counter = 0; counter<cassCogs[0]; counter++ ){
            float temp = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize) *(Float.parseFloat(chainringOne)/cassCogs[counter + 1] ))/1000;
            tvOne[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", temp));

            toEmail_1[counter] = String.format("%.2f", temp);


            float second = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize) *(Float.parseFloat(chainringTwo)/cassCogs[counter + 1] ))/1000;
            tvTwo[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", second));

            toEmail_2[counter] = String.format("%.2f", second);


            float third = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize)*(Float.parseFloat(chainringThree)/cassCogs[counter+ 1] ))/1000;
            tvThree[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", third));

            toEmail_3[counter] = String.format("%.2f", third);

            }
             }
       }
```

Function to email the results

```
      private void mail(){

    Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.calculos));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, composeBody());

    try{
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Mail..."));
    }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Here I write the email body:

```
public String composeBody(){
    String bodyText="";
    String join1="";
    String join2="";
    String join3="";
    if(Integer.parseInt(chainringCount)==1){
        if (toEmail_1.length >0) {
            join1 = implodeArray(toEmail_1, glueString);
        }
        bodyText= bannerText  + lineSep + join1;
    }else if (Integer.parseInt(chainringCount)==2){

        if (toEmail_1.length >0) {
            join1 = implodeArray(toEmail_1, glueString);
        }
        if (toEmail_2.length >0){
            join2=implodeArray(toEmail_2, glueString);
        }
        bodyText= bannerText  + lineSep + join1 + lineSep + join2;
    }else if(Integer.parseInt(chainringCount)==3){
        if (toEmail_1.length >0) {
            join1 = implodeArray(toEmail_1, glueString);
        }
        if (toEmail_2.length >0){
            join2=implodeArray(toEmail_2, glueString);
        }
        if(toEmail_3.length>0) {
            join3=implodeArray(toEmail_3,glueString);
        }
        bodyText= bannerText  + lineSep + join1 + lineSep + join2 + lineSep +join3;         
    }       
    return bodyText;
```

Converting Arrays of strings into strings:

```
 public static String implodeArray(String[] inputArray, String glueString){
String output= "";
if(inputArray.length > 0){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(inputArray[0]);

    for (int i=1; i<inputArray.length;i++){
        sb.append(glueString);
        sb.append(inputArray[i]);
    }
    output=sb.toString();
}
return output;
 }
```

On my phone screen I can see the following: 2 columns, one for each chainring an 10 rows, one for each cog.

[image: Results from doCalculations]

When I send the email with the results, this is what I get:

> ULTEGRA 11-28 * 36/46 
>   2,64 * 3,08 * 3,52 * 3,89 * 4,35 * 4,93 * 5,28 * 5,69 * 6,16 * 6,73 * null
>   3,38 * 3,94 * 4,50 * 4,98 * 5,56 * 6,30 * 6,75 * 7,27 * 7,88 * 8,59 * null

I'm quite lost, Can you give me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Post relevant code please.

Answer (score 0):

Your implodeArray function seems ok, chances are that you're putting those nulls somewhere in the code above. Two quick tests.-

- Try debugging/logging the values you're adding to the arrays, like in

  `toEmail_1[counter] = String.format("%.2f", temp);`
- Just to make sure implodeArray is working, try calling it with a mock array

  `implodeArray(new String[]{"foo1","foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5","foo6"}, "*")`

Comment: implodeArray(,) works okay. I've "toasted" the values for toEmail_[counter] and they match the values displayed on the device screen.

Comment: Looking further into your code, is it possible that at the end of doCalculations you were filling toEmail_2 instead of toEmail_3?

Comment: You're right, checking the code I noticede and sorted it out. There's no phantom array, but the last null on each array is still present. The code above is now edited.

Comment: Could you show how you're initializing the arrays? My guess is that `cassCogs[0]` is one less than the size of your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was easy, thanks to the help of @**ssantos**:

My original declaration of arrays taking into account the maximum capacity

```
String[] toEmail_1 = new String[11];
String[] toEmail_2 = new String[11];
String[] toEmail_3 = new String[11];
```

Now, I set the capacity for the array I'm going to use:

```
   ...else if (Integer.parseInt(chainringCount) == 2){
        toEmail_1 = new String[cassCogs[0]];
        toEmail_2 = new String[cassCogs[0]];

        for (int counter = 0; counter<cassCogs[0]; counter++ ){
            float temp = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize) * (Float.parseFloat(chainringOne) /cassCogs[counter + 1] ))/1000;
            tvOne[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", temp));

            toEmail_1[counter] = String.format("%.2f", temp);

            float second = (Float.parseFloat(wheelsize) *(Float.parseFloat(chainringTwo) /cassCogs[counter+ 1] ))/1000;
            tvTwo[counter].setText(String.format("%.2f", second));

            toEmail_2[counter] = String.format("%.2f", second);

        }
```